# MySQL query WHERE NOT EQUAL not working

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 3 tables in my DB: recipes, ingredients and recipe_ingredients. Recipes and ingredients are connected with many-to-many, so the table recipe_ingredients is a junction table. I want to select all recipes from table recipes, which does not include ingredient with id X. And it's still returns all the recipes. If I write a query to return recipes with ingredient X, it works. Here's my query:

```
select * from recipes
join recipe_ingredients ON recipes.id = recipe_ingredients.fk_Recipe
join ingredients ON recipe_ingredients.fk_Ingredient = ingredients.id
where recipe_ingredients.fk_Ingredient != 307
GROUP by recipes.url
```

Comment: I would advise to use the SQL standard `<>` operator instead of `!=`.

Comment: This also smells of a typical broken MySQL Group By, which I consider a serious design flaw. Surely there are more than 1 column in your select, and there's no aggregate function to be found.

Comment: <> doesn't change anything. If I don't put GROUP By, the result are recipes x ingredients they have. Maybe it's missing something

Comment: If you run it where `fk_Ingredient = 307` does it successfully return only recipes with that ingredient?

Comment: Yes, it does. It returns good results.

Comment: Use proper `GROUP BY`.  You can't use `*` in a `GROUP BY`.    Put all non-aggregated columns in `GROUP BY`. In this case, why do you even use `GROUP BY` if you don't have any aggregation???  Google what `GROUP BY` is used for.

Comment: Why was this downvoted? It's flawed SQL but not a bad question. Rather than just downvote, how about explaining why you thought the question from a new user deserved the downvote.

Comment: @Shawn: I concur. This is maybe not a great question; very likely this is a duplicate of another question from eons ago. Aside from that, I don't see anything in the question that rates a downvote. But such is the way of things in a democracy.

Comment: @AirwaveQ:  A belated welcome from the Stack Overflow community! We're glad you're here. I ask that you please excuse our behavior (downvoting your question), and I encourage you to not be discouraged by the downvoters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any recipe that as an ingredient other than 307 will satisfy the condition.

That is, to this query, it doesn't matter if one of the ingredients is 307, as long as the recipe has some other ingredient other than 307, it's a match.

To get recipes that do not have 307 as an ingredient, we can use an anti-join or a NOT EXISTS

---

*anti-join pattern*

```
 SELECT r.id
      , r.url
   FROM recipes r
   LEFT
   JOIN recipe_ingredients s
     ON s.fk_recipe     = r.id
    AND s.fk_ingredient = 307
  WHERE s.fk_ingredient IS NULL
```

-or-

*not exists pattern*

```
 SELECT r.id
      , r.url
   FROM recipes r
  WHERE NOT EXISTS 
        ( SELECT 1
            FROM recipe_ingredients s
           WHERE s.fk_recipe     = r.id
             AND s.fk_ingredient = 307
        )
```

**FOLLOWUP**

To return recipes that do *not* have 307 as an ingredient, but *do* have 42 as an ingredient...

```
 SELECT r.id
      , r.url
   FROM recipes r
   JOIN recipe_ingredients t
     ON t.fk_recipie    = r.id
    AND t.fk_ingredient = 42 
   LEFT
   JOIN recipe_ingredients s
     ON s.fk_recipe     = r.id
    AND s.fk_ingredient = 307
  WHERE s.fk_ingredient IS NULL
```

-or-

```
 SELECT r.id
      , r.url
   FROM recipes r
  WHERE NOT EXISTS
        ( SELECT 1
            FROM recipe_ingredients s1
           WHERE s1.fk_recipe     = r.id
             AND s1.fk_ingredient = 307
        )
    AND EXISTS 
        ( SELECT 1
            FROM recipe_ingredients s2
           WHERE s2.fk_recipe     = r.id
             AND s2.fk_ingredient = 42
        )
```

Comment: Yes, this one works fine! Thank you. Now I should somehow put this in eloquent ;)

Comment: I'll throw in a vote for the anti-join pattern. It usually performs very well, especially on large datasets.

Comment: Also note that `EXISTS` is a RBAR [https://www.sqlservercentral.com/Forums/Topic642789-338-1.aspx] operation, so it can impact performance.

Comment: @Shawn: my preference is the anti-join pattern, which is why I gave that first. But that anti-join pattern can be difficult for folks to get their brains wrapped around when they first encounter it.... the NOT EXISTS pattern seems much easier to grasp. (Curiously, the EXPLAIN for the anti-join will show "Not exists" in the Extra column, where that doesn't show for the NOT EXISTS pattern.) In terms of performance, my experience is that the two are nearly equivalent; I think MySQL (>=5.6) doesn't perform separate subquery executions, i.e. the SQL looks like it's RBAR but it's not really.

Comment: @spencer7593 Gotcha. It may behave differently in MySQL vs MS T-SQL. MySQL may do a better job of optimizing or figuring out what you really meant. A `NOT EXISTS` would usually perform well since it bails out at the first match (_MUCH_ better than a `NOT IN`), so if your row matches early it'll return quickly. But I'm still not sure it's set-based, whereas the anti-join is.

Comment: @Shawn: yah, with large sets, those correlated subqueries can eat our lunch (and our lunchbox too) if we aren't careful. I *detest* the `NOT IN (subquery)` pattern, and fortunately  I never find myself having to resort to that, if I did, I will make absolutely sure there's no chance that the subquery can  return a NULL)

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you will still include a recipe if it has at least one ingredient that is not 307, as that ingredient will pass the `where` condition.

You could use a `having` condition, like this:

```
select   recipes.url 
from     recipes
    join recipe_ingredients on recipes.id = recipe_ingredients.fk_Recipe
    join ingredients        on ingredients.id = recipe_ingredients.fk_Ingredient
group by recipes.url 
having   not(sum(recipe_ingredients.fk_Ingredient = 307))
```

When using this in combination with "positive" conditions, i.e. where a certain ingredient *must* be used, then keep using the same pattern, but this time without `not`:

```
select   recipes.url 
from     recipes
    join recipe_ingredients on recipes.id = recipe_ingredients.fk_Recipe
    join ingredients        on ingredients.id = recipe_ingredients.fk_Ingredient
group by recipes.url 
having   not(sum(recipe_ingredients.fk_Ingredient = 307))
   and   sum(recipe_ingredients.fk_Ingredient = 1105)
```

When on top of that you have conditions on the number of ingredients, then add a `count` condition in the `having` clause, for instance:

```
select   recipes.url 
from     recipes
    join recipe_ingredients on recipes.id = recipe_ingredients.fk_Recipe
    join ingredients        on ingredients.id = recipe_ingredients.fk_Ingredient
group by recipes.url 
having   not(sum(recipe_ingredients.fk_Ingredient = 307))
   and   sum(recipe_ingredients.fk_Ingredient = 1105)
   and   count(*) = 2
```

This method should be very efficient: it does not require to perform a sub query or to join the same table more than once.

Comment: In this case, it works. But if I put `where`, it doesn't work anymore. For example, I need to find recipes, which has ingredient X, but doesn't have ingredient Y. `select * from recipes
join recipe_ingredients ON recipes.id = recipe_ingredients.fk_Recipe
join ingredients ON recipe_ingredients.fk_Ingredient = ingredients.id
where recipe_ingredients.fk_Ingredient = 1105
group by recipes.url 
having sum(recipe_ingredients.fk_Ingredient = 307) = 0`

Comment: to note a corner case... this query won't return a recipe that has no ingredients. This requires a recipe have at least one ingredient....

Comment: Honestly I would like to find a recipe without ingredients. It would make my cooking so much cheaper. But on a serious note, just wrap the sum in `coalesce(..., 0)`  for that corner case.

Comment: Instead of using a `where` clause for a positive test, use the same pattern again within tha `having` clause, but with `>0`

Comment: As I mentioned, it's a *corner* case, it's so remote, that it doesn't even qualify as an *edge* case. You're right, a "recipe" without "ingredients" doesn't make much sense But this query does satisfy a slightly different specification ... "recipes with at least one ingredient that does not have 307 as an ingredient." In the more general case, that distinction can be important.

Comment: In that last case the corner case does not apply: the original query would then just need to be extended with the  `count(*) = 1` condition in the `where` clause. I have updated the answer in view of your comments.